# Algebraically expanding this function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I have an algebra question.

I am currently working on this function:

$$\left(\frac{{e^{t\sqrt{3/n}}} -{e^{-t\sqrt{3/n}}}}{2t\sqrt{3/n}}\right)^n$$

Now this is the MGF of a function called $Z$ and I have to find the MGF as $n$ goes to $\infty$ which of course, since I am using the CLT, will have to be $e^{t^2/2}$ (the MGF of the Standard Normal). All of this is correct, it's just that I am having difficulty simplifying this. I also know that I need to use the following:

$(1+a/n)^n$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ is equal to $e^a$.

Help would be greatly appreciated as I am quite unsure of how to proceed. I do not even know where to begin as the function is raised to the power of $n$.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hints or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $y=t \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}\;$ your expression becomes
$$f(t,n) := \left(\frac{e^y - e^{-y}}{2y}\right)^n = \left(\frac{\sinh y}{y}\right)^n$$
Now for large $n$ i.e. small $y$ we use the Taylor series
$$\frac{\sinh y}{y} = 1+\frac{1}{6}y^2 + \frac{1}{120}y^4+O(y^5)$$
It is easier to approximate $\ln f(t,n)\;$ using an other Taylor series (for small $x$):
$$\ln(1+x)= x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4+O(x^5)$$
With these definitions and tools we can get
$$\ln f(t,n) = \ln \left(\left(\frac{\sinh y}{y}\right)^n\right)
=n \ln \left(\frac{\sinh y}{y}\right) 
\approx n \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{6}y^2 + \frac{1}{120}y^4+O(y^5)\right)
\approx n  \left(\frac{1}{6}y^2 + O(y^3)\right)
=n  \left(\frac{1}{6}t^2\frac{3}{n} + O(n^{-3/2})\right)
=\frac{1}{2}t^2 + O(n^{-1/2})
$$
and this will give the approximation $e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$.

Please note that this is the basic idea; with more terms in the series you will get better error estimates.

Comment: Thanks so much , crystal clear !